# ORDS POST work but not PUT on the same database

Tags: sql, oracle-autonomous-db

When I test ORDS POST works perfectly but I get "555 User Defined Resource Error" when running PUT and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

> PUT Received:
> {
> "code": "UserDefinedResourceError",
> "title": "User Defined Resource Error",
> "message": "The request could not be processed due to an error in a user defined resource",
> "o:errorCode": "ORDS-25001",
> "cause": "An error occurred when evaluating the SQL statement associated with this resource. SQL Error Code 6550, Error Message: ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_PLAYER'\nORA-06550: line 2, column 5:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n",

I have posted the same problem in another post that I solved by adopting the date but have not been able to fix this yet.

I would very much appreciate any ideas and help as I do not understand why POST work but not PUT.

Here is the definitions:

[image]

```
create or replace PROCEDURE UNITY.post_player (
    playerid IN players.playerId%TYPE,
    playername IN players.playername%TYPE,
    registrationdate IN VARCHAR2,
    datelastactivity IN VARCHAR2,
    nrofdayssincelastactivity IN players.nrofdayssincelastactivity%TYPE,
    diffandround IN players.diffandround%TYPE,
    nrsingleplayermatches IN players.nrsingleplayermatches%TYPE,
    nrmultiplayermatches IN players.nrmultiplayermatches%TYPE,
    nrmatches IN players.nrmatches%TYPE,
    nrquitmatches IN players.nrquitmatches%TYPE,
    nrflips IN players.nrflips%TYPE,
    nrclicks IN players.nrclicks%TYPE,
    totmatchtimesec IN players.totmatchtimesec%TYPE,
    score IN players.score%TYPE,
    nrwonmatches IN players.nrwonmatches%TYPE,
    nrlostmatches IN players.nrlostmatches%TYPE,
    nrevenmatches IN players.nrevenmatches%TYPE,
    templnrmatches IN players.templnrmatches%TYPE,
    templmatchtimesec IN players.templmatchtimesec%TYPE,
    qualified IN players.qualified%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO players (
    playerid,
    playername,
    registrationdate,
    datelastactivity,
    nrofdayssincelastactivity,
    diffandround,
    nrsingleplayermatches,
    nrmultiplayermatches,
    nrmatches,
    nrquitmatches,
    nrflips,
    nrclicks,
    totmatchtimesec,
    score,
    nrwonmatches,
    nrlostmatches,
    nrevenmatches,
    templnrmatches,
    templmatchtimesec,
    qualified)
VALUES (
    playerid, 
    playername,
    TO_DATE(registrationdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    TO_DATE(datelastactivity, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    nrofdayssincelastactivity,
    diffandround,
    nrsingleplayermatches,
    nrmultiplayermatches,
    nrmatches,
    nrquitmatches,
    nrflips,
    nrclicks,
    totmatchtimesec,
    score,
    nrwonmatches,
    nrlostmatches,
    nrevenmatches,
    templnrmatches,
    templmatchtimesec,
    qualified);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END;
```

Post JSON:

```
{ 
    "playerid":"2222", 
    "playername":"HANNAH", 
    "registrationdate":"2022-07-01", 
    "datelastactivity":"2022-07-01", 
    "nrofdayssincelastactivity":4, 
    "diffandround":"D0R0", 
    "nrsingleplayermatches":1, 
    "nrmultiplayermatches":0, 
    "nrmatches":1, 
    "nrquitmatches":0, 
    "nrflips":8, 
    "nrclicks":16, 
    "totmatchtimesec":30.68, 
    "score":16, 
    "nrwonmatches":0, 
    "nrlostmatches":0, 
    "nrevenmatches":0, 
    "templnrmatches":0, 
    "templmatchtimesec":0.0, 
    "qualified":0 
}
```

POST template:

```
BEGIN
        post_player(
        playerid => :playerid,
            playername => :playername,
            registrationdate => :registrationdate,
            datelastactivity => :datelastactivity,
            nrofdayssincelastactivity => :nrofdayssincelastactivity,
            diffandround => :diffandround,
            nrsingleplayermatches => :nrsingleplayermatches,
            nrmultiplayermatches => :nrmultiplayermatches,
            nrmatches => :nrmatches,
            nrquitmatches => :nrquitmatches,
            nrflips => :nrflips,
            nrclicks => :nrclicks,
            totmatchtimesec => :totmatchtimesec,
            score => :score,
            nrwonmatches => :nrwonmatches,
            nrlostmatches => :nrlostmatches,
            nrevenmatches => :nrevenmatches,
            templnrmatches => :templnrmatches,
            templmatchtimesec => :templmatchtimesec,
            qualified => :qualified
        );
END;
```

Here is the PUT:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE UNITY.put_player (
    p_playerid IN players.playerid%TYPE,
    p_playername IN players.playername%TYPE,
    p_registrationdate IN VARCHAR2,
    p_datelastactivity IN VARCHAR2,
    p_nrofdayssincelastactivity IN players.nrofdayssincelastactivity%TYPE,
    p_diffandround IN players.diffandround%TYPE,
    p_nrsingleplayermatches IN players.nrsingleplayermatches%TYPE,
    p_nrmultiplayermatches IN players.nrmultiplayermatches%TYPE,
    p_nrmatches IN players.nrmatches%TYPE,
    p_nrquitmatches IN players.nrquitmatches%TYPE,
    p_nrflips IN players.nrflips%TYPE,
    p_nrclicks IN players.nrclicks%TYPE,
    p_totmatchtimesec IN players.totmatchtimesec%TYPE,
    p_score IN players.score%TYPE,
    p_nrwonmatches IN players.nrwonmatches%TYPE,
    p_nrlostmatches IN players.nrlostmatches%TYPE,
    p_nrevenmatches IN players.nrevenmatches%TYPE,
    p_templnrmatches IN players.templnrmatches%TYPE,
    p_templmatchtimesec IN players.templmatchtimesec%TYPE,
    p_qualified IN players.qualified%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE PLAYERS SET
    --playerid = p_playerid,
    playername = p_playername,
    registrationdate = TO_DATE(p_registrationdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    datelastactivity = TO_DATE(p_datelastactivity, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    nrofdayssincelastactivity = p_nrofdayssincelastactivity,
    diffandround = p_diffandround,
    nrsingleplayermatches = p_nrsingleplayermatches,
    nrmultiplayermatches = p_nrmultiplayermatches,
    nrmatches = p_nrmatches,
    nrquitmatches = p_nrquitmatches,
    nrflips = p_nrflips,
    nrclicks = p_nrclicks,
    totmatchtimesec = p_totmatchtimesec,
    score = p_score,
    nrwonmatches = p_nrwonmatches,
    nrlostmatches = p_nrlostmatches,
    nrevenmatches = p_nrevenmatches,
    templnrmatches = p_templnrmatches,
    templmatchtimesec = p_templmatchtimesec,
    qualified = p_qualified
WHERE playerid = p_playerid;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END;
```

PUT template:

```
BEGIN
put_player(
   playerid                  => :playerid,
   playername                => :playername,
   registrationdate          => :registrationdate,
   datelastactivity          => :datelastactivity,
   nrofdayssincelastactivity => :nrofdayssincelastactivity,
   diffandround              => :diffandround,
   nrsingleplayermatches     => :nrsingleplayermatches,
   nrmultiplayermatches      => :nrmultiplayermatches,
   nrmatches                 => :nrmatches,
   nrquitmatches             => :nrquitmatches,
   nrflips                   => :nrflips,
   nrclicks                  => :nrclicks,
   totmatchtimesec           => :totmatchtimesec,
   score                     => :score,
   nrwonmatches              => :nrwonmatches,
   nrlostmatches             => :nrlostmatches,
   nrevenmatches             => :nrevenmatches,
   templnrmatches            => :templnrmatches,
   templmatchtimesec         => :templmatchtimesec,
   qualified                 => :qualified);
END;
```

PUT json:

```
{ 
    "playerid":"2222", 
    "playername":"Zappa", 
    "registrationdate":"2022-07-01", 
    "datelastactivity":"2022-07-01", 
    "nrofdayssincelastactivity":4, 
    "diffandround":"D0R0", 
    "nrsingleplayermatches":1, 
    "nrmultiplayermatches":0, 
    "nrmatches":1, 
    "nrquitmatches":0, 
    "nrflips":8, 
    "nrclicks":16, 
    "totmatchtimesec":30.68, 
    "score":16, 
    "nrwonmatches":0, 
    "nrlostmatches":0, 
    "nrevenmatches":0, 
    "templnrmatches":0, 
    "templmatchtimesec":0.0, 
    "qualified":0 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest I am still not 100% sure what exactly caused this but I finally succeeded to get it to work, inspired by @thatjeffsmith suggestion.

I reviewed and re-did all the code for PUT as this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE put_player (
    p_playerid                    IN  PLAYERS.playerid%TYPE,
    p_playername                  IN  PLAYERS.playername%TYPE,
    p_registrationdate            IN  VARCHAR2,
    p_datelastactivity            IN  VARCHAR2,
    p_nrofdayssincelastactivity   IN  PLAYERS.nrofdayssincelastactivity%TYPE,
    p_diffandround                IN  PLAYERS.diffandround%TYPE,
    p_nrsingleplayermatches       IN  PLAYERS.nrsingleplayermatches%TYPE,
    p_nrmultiplayermatches        IN  PLAYERS.nrmultiplayermatches%TYPE,
    p_nrmatches                   IN  PLAYERS.nrmatches%TYPE,
    p_nrquitmatches               IN  PLAYERS.nrquitmatches%TYPE,
    p_nrflips                     IN  PLAYERS.nrflips%TYPE,
    p_nrclicks                    IN  PLAYERS.nrclicks%TYPE,
    p_totmatchtimesec             IN  PLAYERS.totmatchtimesec%TYPE,
    p_score                       IN  PLAYERS.score%TYPE,
    p_nrwonmatches                IN  PLAYERS.nrwonmatches%TYPE,
    p_nrlostmatches               IN  PLAYERS.nrlostmatches%TYPE,
    p_nrevenmatches               IN  PLAYERS.nrevenmatches%TYPE,
    p_templnrmatches              IN  PLAYERS.templnrmatches%TYPE,
    p_templmatchtimesec           IN  PLAYERS.templmatchtimesec%TYPE,
    p_qualified                   IN  PLAYERS.qualified%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE PLAYERS
SET   
    playerid                    = p_playerid,
    playername                  = p_playername,
    registrationdate            = TO_DATE(p_registrationdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), --'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
    datelastactivity            = TO_DATE(p_datelastactivity, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), --'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),           
    nrofdayssincelastactivity   = p_nrofdayssincelastactivity,
    diffandround                = p_diffandround,
    nrsingleplayermatches       = p_nrsingleplayermatches,
    nrmultiplayermatches        = p_nrmultiplayermatches,
    nrmatches                   = p_nrmatches,
    nrquitmatches               = p_nrquitmatches,
    nrflips                     = p_nrflips,
    nrclicks                    = p_nrclicks,
    totmatchtimesec             = p_totmatchtimesec,
    score                       = p_score,
    nrwonmatches                = p_nrwonmatches,
    nrlostmatches               = p_nrlostmatches,
    nrevenmatches               = p_nrevenmatches,
    templnrmatches              = p_templnrmatches,
    templmatchtimesec           = p_templmatchtimesec,
    qualified                   = p_qualified
WHERE playerid  = p_playerid;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END;
/


BEGIN
    ORDS.define_template(
    p_module_name    => 'players',
    p_pattern        => 'put_player/');

ORDS.define_handler(
    p_module_name    => 'players',
    p_pattern        => 'put_player/',
    p_method         => 'PUT',
    p_source_type    => ORDS.source_type_plsql,
    p_source         => 'BEGIN
    
    put_player(
          p_playerid                  => :playerid,
          p_playername                => :playername,
          p_registrationdate          => :registrationdate,
          p_datelastactivity          => :datelastactivity,
          p_nrofdayssincelastactivity => :nrofdayssincelastactivity,
          p_diffandround              => :diffandround,
          p_nrsingleplayermatches     => :nrsingleplayermatches,
          p_nrmultiplayermatches      => :nrmultiplayermatches,
          p_nrmatches                 => :nrmatches,
          p_nrquitmatches             => :nrquitmatches,
          p_nrflips                   => :nrflips,
          p_nrclicks                  => :nrclicks,  
          p_totmatchtimesec           => :totmatchtimesec,
          p_score                     => :score,
          p_nrwonmatches              => :nrwonmatches,
          p_nrlostmatches             => :nrlostmatches,
          p_nrevenmatches             => :nrevenmatches,
          p_templnrmatches            => :templnrmatches,
          p_templmatchtimesec         => :templmatchtimesec,
          p_qualified                 => :qualified
  );
    END;',
    p_items_per_page => 0);

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

...and it works!

BTW, I am learning this now.